# DC Voltage stabiliser

Tags: dc-dc-converter, adapter, stable

I have a fluctuating DC voltage in the range 8.5-9.5V coming out from an adapter. How can I convert it to a stable 9V?

Comment: (1) How much current do you need to draw from the adapter?  (2) Does the voltage have to be exactly 9V?  Will stable 7V do?

Comment: I have not done the current calculations but I do need exactly 9V.

Answer (score 2):

You need a buck-boost DC-DC converter (because your input voltage range is both above and below your output voltage). You can buy an existing converter or build your own.

Keep in mind that it may be better to ditch your existing adapter and use something else e.g. get a 12V adapter, and put that through a 9V linear regulator. Or get a different adapter that outputs 9V on its own, depending on your tolerances for ripple/noise/etc.